# integrate giving wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier, fixed as of 11.3**

---

A question with the same title has been asked many times, but I can't find the solution of my problem in their answers. The integral I am trying to calculate is

```
Integrate[Sin[q ]^2 / Sinh[q]^2, {q, 0, ∞}]
```

which gives me

```
1/4 (-1 + 2 π Coth[π])
```

The correct result is

```
1/4 (-2 + 2 π Coth[π])
```

This is a tabulated integral, see for instance Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 3.982.3

Why is *Mathematica* wrong here? Most issues I have seen were due to variables in the integral, which I don't have (at least not in this example, in the actual integral that I am computing I have variables).

Comment: Version and OS, please. (Note that 5.2 gets it right…)

Comment: Version 10.4.1 on Linux (Gentoo, if that matters)

Comment: Please report this to Wolfram support.

Comment: I have, I will post updates if they have a solution.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is wrong as well ... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSin%5Bq+%5D%5E2+%2F+Sinh%5Bq%5D%5E2,+%7Bq,+0,+%E2%88%9E%7D%5D

Comment: In the meantime: take the Laplace transform of your integrand, and let the transform variable go to zero.

Comment: Or use `GenerateConditions -> False`, gives correct answer, makes you feel ucky...

Comment: @ciao Somehow I forgot about `GenerateConditions -> False`...I was taking the long way 'round: `Limit[Series[DSolveValue[{y'[q] == Sin[q]^2/Sinh[q]^2, y[0] == 0}, y[q], q], {q, Infinity, 1}], q -> Infinity]`.

Comment: Why does `GenerateConditions -> False` change the result (or even the algorithm behind it) if there are no parameters that possibly could cause conditions?

Comment: The bug has been confirmed by `Mathematica` developers.

Comment: Can somebody with access to earlier versions add the header, please?

Comment: Update: The integral returns unevaluated in V11.2.

Comment: On 11.3.0 for Mac OS X the integral gives the correct result.

Comment: I can confirm, on Linux version 11.3.0 also gives the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

You get the right result, if you first solve the indefinite integral and then take the upper and lower limit (using MMA version 8.0)

```
int[q_] = Integrate[Sin[q]^2/Sinh[q]^2, q, Assumptions -> q > 0]

(*     1/8 E^(-2 I q) (-4 E^(2 I q) Coth[q] + 2 (1 + E^(4 I q)) Coth[q] + 
       2 Hypergeometric2F1[-I, 1, 1 - I, E^(2 q)] + 
       2 E^(4 I q) Hypergeometric2F1[I, 1, 1 + I, E^(2 q)] + (1 - I) E^(
       2 q) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - I, 2 - I, E^(
       2 q)] + (1 + I) E^((2 + 4 I) q)
       Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + I, 2 + I, E^(2 q)])     *)

lim0 = Limit[int[q], q -> 0, Direction -> -1] // FullSimplify

(*     1/2 \[Pi] Coth[\[Pi]]     *)

liminf = Limit[int[q], q -> \[Infinity]] // FullSimplify

(*     -(1/2) + \[Pi] Coth[\[Pi]]     *)

{buf = liminf - lim0, N[buf]}

(*     {-(1/2) + 1/2 \[Pi] Coth[\[Pi]], 1.07667}     *)
```